# Overloaded cast and postincrement operators - wrong order

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my c++ program.

I created a class that represents modulo number.

Let's say it looks like:

```
template <typename Type> class Cycler
{
    public:
        Cycler(Type Mod) : CurrentIndex(0), Mod(Mod)
        {}

        Cycler & operator ++ ()
        {
            F();
            return *this;
        }
        Type operator ++ (int)
        {
            F();
            return CurrentIndex;
        }
        Cycler & operator -- ()
        {
            B();
            return *this;
        }
        Type operator -- (int)
        {
            B();
            return CurrentIndex;
        }
        operator Type()
        {
            return CurrentIndex;
        }
    protected:
        void F()
        {
            if((++CurrentIndex) == Mod)
                CurrentIndex = 0;
        }
        void B()
        {
            if(CurrentIndex == 0)
                CurrentIndex = Mod - 1;
            else
                CurrentIndex--;
        }
        Type CurrentIndex, Mod;
};
```

But let's say I'm doing:

```
Cycler<unsigned int> C(100);
unsigned int I1 = C; // IS 0, OK
I1 = ++C; //Is 1 - OK
I2 = C++; //Is 2 - NOT OK
```

If i do:

```
...
I2 = C;
C++;

//It is ok
```

I think this is a problem with oreder of operators executed - my number is incremented after ++, but before being casted to unsigned int.

How can I make this work?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) for operator overloading techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you implement the post-increment operator by saying:

```
    Cycler operator ++ (int)
    {
        Cycler tmp = *this;
        F();
        return tmp;
    }
```

Post-increment and post-decrement operators normally return the object as it was before the increment/decrement. Thus they have to create a copy of the original state of the object before alteration.

---

Btw, arithmetic for unsigned types is slightly different than for signed types. unsigned integers are defined to [wrap around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). For example if you have an `unsigned char`, 255+1 is 0 again. Same for 0-1 = 255. This is not undefined behavior as opposed to signed integers!

So in your case you can just simplify `F()` to `i = (i+1) % n` and `B()` to `i = (i-1) % n`.